# Exact values in point labels - R plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am working on school project and need to assign exact values to points that i drew on the plot using Rstudio and to print them on the plot. Do you know theoritically how to make it? I need to get this kind of view:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxmFc.png)]

I can only use graphics from other visualistion packets among in R.

I tried to do this by using this kind of the formula:

```
text(
  x=d$proc_oze~id,
  y=d,
  labels=paste("pkt",1:nrow(d))
)
```

and then such an error occured:

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data)

If needed i can provide data or whole formula - just hmu.

Comment: There is a function in base graphics that lets you evaluate the position of the pointer. In base R the tilde character creates a formula. You should say what you were expecting. The tidyverse use of the tilde operator is ‘non-standard’.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

One way to use `text()` is like this

```
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x*x
y2  <- 2*y1
# Create a first line
plot(x, y1, type = "b", frame = FALSE, pch = 19, 
     col = "red", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
# Add a second line
lines(x, y2, pch = 18, col = "blue", type = "b", lty = 2)
# Add a legend to the plot
legend("topleft", legend=c("Line 1", "Line 2"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty = 1:2, cex=0.8)
text(x, y1+3, y1)
```

[image]

More info: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/line-plots-r-base-graphs
https://statisticsglobe.com/text-function-plot-r/

Comment: Thanks, I used this: text(
  x=d$id,
  y=d$proc_oze,
  labels=paste(d$proc_oze,1:nrow(d))) and helped. Now any idea how to reduce numbers to 2 decimal places?

Comment: `....labels=paste(round(d$proc_oze, 2), 1:nrow(d)))...`